# What is the measure-theoretic definition of the conditional Wiener measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The Wiener measure $W$ on the space of (continuous, a posteriori) curves defined on $[0,t]$ is uniquely characterized by being Borel and having prescribed pushforwards (that I shall not write here). It is immediate that $W$ is concentrated on the space of curves that start in $0 \in \mathbb R^n$ at time $0$.

> What is the rigorous definition of the *conditional* Wiener measure?

Intuitively, I understand the conditional Wiener measure $W_p$ to be a Borel measure, with very similar pushforwards (I know them, I shall not write them here), but concentrated on the curves that also have the endpoint fixed: at time $t$ they arrive in $p \in \mathbb R^n$. It follows that $\int _{\mathbb R^n} W_p (A) \ \mathrm d p = W(A)$ for all Borel subsets $A$ of the space of curves. The problem is that this cannot be a definition, because nothing guarantees the uniqueness (and pointwise existence) of the disintegration $p \mapsto W_p$ of $W$ like in the formula above (the disintegration theorem *does* provide uniqueness *almost everywhere*, but under assumptions about the pushforward of $W$ that are definitely not met here).

(Please provide measure-theoretic explanations, not probabilistic ones, because I am not familiar with the probabilistic language.)

Comment: That formula definitely looks wrong. If $W_p$ is concentrated on paths arriving at $p$ at time $t$, then you'd want something like $$\int_{\Bbb R^n} W_p(A) q_t(p)dp=W(A),$$ where $q_t$ is the transition density of BM from $0$ to $p$ at time $t$.

Comment: But isn't $q_t$ already contained in $W_p$? If I view $W_p$ as a functional on the space of continuous bounded functions, and  if $h(t,x,y) = (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(-\frac {|x-y|^2} {4t})$ is the heat kernel, isn't $W_p (1) = h(t,p,0)$? In which case $W_p (1)$ must simply be integrated with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mathrm d p$ in order to get $W(1)$?

Comment: Usually we want the $W_p$ to be probability measures.

Comment: @Shalop: I'm lost, because results 2.20 - 2.22 on page 8 of ["Wiener measures on Riemannian manifolds and the Feynman-Kac formula" by C. Bär and F. Pfäffle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5082) claim otherwise (along the lines of my interpretation).

Comment: Well if you had a reference then post it in the first place! Your question is full of ambiguities. Also, it seems to just be a convention. Those authors are calling $W_p$ what I would ordinarily call $q_t(p)\cdot W_p$. I prefer the latter since it has a nice probabilistic interpretation

Comment: @Shalop: Things are simple and there is no need to raise the voice: I haven't included any reference because I believed that there is a single notion of conditional Wiener measure - the one that I was familiar with (in the same way that you believed that there is a single such concept - the one that you were familiar with). My question is no more ambiguous than your answer. How was I supposed to know that mathematicians still haven't settled this simple issue? Also, notice that on Riemannian manifolds it is no longer true that $W$ is a probability; it remains true, though, that $W(1) \le 1$.

Comment: Raise the voice? Sorry, there was a misunderstanding. I didn't mean it like that. And yes, on a Riemannian manifold a Brownian particle can indeed die in finite time, if it's not closed and compact (I think).

Answer (score 2):

[In your integration formula, $dp$ should be replaced by $(2\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(-|p|^2/2t)\,dp$.]

One way to present $W_p$ is as the image of $W$ under the transformation sending the path $\{x(s), 0\le s\le t\}$ to the path $[0,t] \ni s\mapsto x(s)-(s/t)[x(t)-p]$. This choice makes the disintegration formula true, and $p\mapsto W_p$ is weak${}^*$ continuous, not just measurable. As such it is unique.

By the way, as the space of continuous functions mapping $[0,t]$ to $\Bbb R^n$ is Polish, a standard disintegration theorem does apply to yield an a.e. determined family $\{W_p: p\in\Bbb R^n\}$. This general result only ensures that $p\mapsto W_p(A)$ is Borel for Borel $A$.

Comment: If your first line is correct (which seems to be the crux of the problem), then my understanding of $W_p$ is a bit skewed; please bear with me for a little longer. If I view $W_p$ as a functional on the space of continuous bounded functions, and  if $h(t,x,y) = (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(-\frac {|x-y|^2} {4t})$ is the heat kernel, isn't $W_p (1) = h(t,p,0)$? In which case $W_p (1)$ must simply be integrated with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mathrm d p$ in order to get $W(1)$?

Comment: To clarify: my understading of the conditional Wiener measure is the one in results 2.20 - 2.22 on page 8 of ["Wiener measures on Riemannian manifolds and the Feynman-Kac formula" by C. Bär and F. Pfäffle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5082), that claim otherwise than in this answer.

Comment: Our only important difference is that (because I am a probabilist) my  $W_p$ is normalized to be a conditional probability; intuitively, $W_p(\cdot) :=W(\cdot\,|\,x(t) =p)$.  Your $W_p$ is un-normalized.  Bär and Pfäffle (who,  I presume, are physicists) use un-normalized $W_p$.

Comment: Let me come back to this question, please: do you know how to prove that the mapping $p \mapsto W_p$ (the "conditioning") is continuous *on Riemannian manifolds*? The argument that you gave no longer works, for there is no underlying linear structure anymore. I am sure that continuity is preserved, but I do not know how to show it.

Comment: The paper "Markovian bridges: Weak continuity and pathwise constructions" (by L. Chaumont and G. Uribe Bravo; Ann. Probab. **39* (2011) 609-647.) looks to have what you need -- the crucial thing is that the transition densities exist and are continuous, which is true for the Wiener measure.

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I had found that paper myself. Notice that proof of theorem 5 therein (which is crucial for the stated result) is wrong (I do not know how), as acknowledged by Uribe himself in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4184v3.pdf.